# How to group insert statments into transactions when using ogr PGDump driver?

Tags: postgresql, ogr2ogr

I tried the `-gt` option to group insert statements into transactions, but apparently it doesn't make a difference:

`ogr2ogr -f PGDump test1.sql test_6350.gpkg -lco SRID=6350 -lco DIM=2 -nlt PROMOTE_TO_MULTI -gt 50000`

`ogr2ogr -f PGDump test2.sql test_6350.gpkg -lco SRID=6350 -lco DIM=2 -nlt PROMOTE_TO_MULTI -gt 100000`

`diff test1.sql test2.sql` is empty.

There are as many `INSERT` statements as the number of features in  `test_6350.gpkg`, ~2 million. I could grep only one line with a `COMMIT` in it. So next when I try `psql "connection string ..." -f test1.sql` how is it going to know how `inserts` are grouped?

Answer (score 2):

In ogr2ogr the `-gt` option is the correct and only way to control the size of the transactions https://gdal.org/programs/ogr2ogr.html#cmdoption-ogr2ogr-gt

> -gt n
>
> Group n features per transaction (default 100 000). Increase the value for better performance when writing into DBMS drivers that have
> transaction support. n can be set to unlimited to load the data into a
> single transaction.

I verified that with the PGDump driver `-gt` does not have any effect but the whole data is written within a single transaction.

By the GDAL RFC 54 there are only a few drivers that support transactions:PG, GPKG, SQLite, FileGDB, OCI, MySQL, MSSQLSpatial  https://gdal.org/development/rfc/rfc54_dataset_transactions.html#rfc-54. RFC documents are final so it is possible that some drivers have received transaction support since the RFC was written but obviously PGDump has not.

You can write mail to gdal-dev mailing list and ask if adding transactions into PGDump feels reasonable.

When you create the PGDump files I suggest to consider using the configuration option `--config PG_USE_COPY YES`. It will create SQL like

`COPY "public"."states" ("wkb_geometry", "state_name", "state_fips", "sub_region", "state_abbr", "land_km", "water_km", "persons", "families", "houshold", "male", "female", "workers", "drvalone", "carpool", "pubtrans", "employed", "unemploy", "service", "manual", "p_male", "p_female", "samp_pop", "wkt_geom") FROM STDIN; 0106000020E610000001000000010300000001000000460100008AE42B81940456C0A24ACD1E68C14240F6B704E09F0556C...`

That is much faster to insert into the database, though the data part is not understandable for humans.